# Redirect WordPress Permalinks to Simple Post Name

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I want to 301 redirect my entire WordPress money site from https:// moneysite.com/%category%/%postname%/ to simply https:// moneysite.com/%postname%/ , but exclude everything in a CPT called 'team' which uses the permalink like https://www.moneysite.com/team/rogger/. I have googled for this, but didn't come up with anything, or I didn't think what I saw was right.

I also want to redirect http to https and remove the www from the permalink. Please guide me a bit. It will be very helpful for me as i am spending countless hours in setting this up.

I got a code but it's not excluding and removing permalink "Team" from the pages as well.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ https://moneysite.com/$2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will exclude team (and make the last forward slash optional):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/team/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/products/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ https://moneysite.com/$2 [L,R=301]
```

This goes just after it and will remove www and/or redirect to HTTPS:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=moneysite.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^ https://moneysite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

To go in root .htaccess file.

Comment: Thanks @superDuperApps, Can you please tell me how can i make the last forward slash must. It will create duplicate content issues,

Comment: One More issue, If i want to exclude two CPTs like Team and Products..How will we do that?

Comment: It won't create duplicate content issues. It's a redirect. It just means the redirect will work if the forward slash is missing from the end. It doesn't mean two copies of the same page are being served with or without it. They both redirect to the same thing, which is no forward slash, as you had it. If you want to stop it redirecting without the forward slash just remove the question mark at the end of the regex in the first RewriteRule. And if you're making use of my answer please use the tick on the top left of it to show you accept it. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I added another condition to exclude /products/.

Comment: Thanks a lot but it's creating one more issue. It's breaking WP-Admin section and removing wp-admin from the domain as well. How to run it only on the frontend.

Comment: All you can do is add conditions for each top level folder you want to avoid being processed. So just add one for wp-admin.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a redirect in your server/site configuration, for example a [RedirectMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) in your .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/\d\d\d\d/\d+/\d+/(.*) /$1
```